# Resolver arvore genealógica com PROLOG

Tags: prolog

Estou com uma dificuldade em criar algumas relações.
Segue a tabela:

```
homem(jose).
homem(ananias).
homem(helio).
homem(jurandir).
homem(valdir).
homem(delio).
homem(fabiano).
homem(willian).
homem(diego).
homem(mateus).
homem(henrique).
mulher(generosa).
mulher(tereza).
mulher(maria).
mulher(nilzete).
mulher(ildete).
mulher(jaqueline).
mulher(gislaine).
mulher(jaqueline).
mulher(livia).
mulher(isabela).
mulher(maria_e).
casado(jose, generosa).
casado(ananias, tereza).
casado(delio, maria).
casado(jurandir, nilzete).
casado(delio, ildete).
casado(willian, jaqueline).
casado(diego, gislaine).
progenitor(jose, helio).
progenitor(generosa, helio).
progenitor(jose, jurandir).
progenitor(generosa, jurandir).
progenitor(ananias, nilzete).
progenitor(tereza, nilzete).
progenitor(ananias, valdir).
progenitor(tereza, valdir).
progenitor(ananias, ildete).
progenitor(tereza, ildete).
progenitor(helio, fabiano).
progenitor(maria, fabiano).
progenitor(jurandir, willian).
progenitor(nilzete, willian).
progenitor(jurandir, gislaine).
progenitor(nilzete, gislaine).
progenitor(delio, jaqueline).
progenitor(ildete, jaqueline).
progenitor(willian, henrique).
progenitor(jaqueline, henrique).
progenitor(willian, livia).
progenitor(jaqueline, livia).
progenitor(diego, isabela).
progenitor(gislaine, isabela).
progenitor(diego, maria_e).
progenitor(gislaine, maria_e).
progenitor(fabiano, mateus).
```

Preciso das seguintes regra de relações:
Pai, mãe, avó paterna, irmãos, irmão, irmãos completos, sogro, tio, neto, relação antepassado.

Pai e mae estou fazendo desta maneira:

```
pai(X,Y) :- homem(Y), progenitor(Y,X).
mae(X,Y) :- mulher(Y), progenitor(Y,X).
```

Mas apos retornar a mãe ou pai, tem um retorno `false`.

Irmãos fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
irmao(X,Y) :- progenitor(HOMEM,X), progenitor(HOMEM,Y), X \== Y.
```

Mas nesse caso so retorna irmão por parte de pai.
Preciso de uma regra para retornar irmão com pelo menos uma relação entre pai ou mãe.

Answer (score 1):

Executando a primeira query obtive a seguinte resposta:

```
?- pai(jurandir,willian).
false.

?- pai(willian,jurandir).
true .

?- pai(willian,Y).

Y = jurandir .
```

Vamos entender o que está acontecendo antes de
abordamos o problema propriamente dito vendo o trace:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Talvez seja necessário apenas que tu organizes tuas regras.
Eu faria: `pai(X,Y) :- homem(X), progenitor(X,Y)`.

> Lê-se: "X é pai de Y  caso X seja homem E X seja progenitor de Y"

Para encontrar o irmão, tua regra precisa apenas de um complemento:

```
irmao(X,Y):-homem(X), pai(Z,X), pai(Z,Y),X\=Y.
irmao(X,Y):-homem(X), mae(Z,X), mae(Z,Y),X\=Y.
```

Realizando as consultas:

```
?- irmao(helio,jurandir).
true .

?- irmao(henrique,livia).
true .
```

Acrescentando o segunte fato para testar meio irmão:

> progenitor(gislaine, mateus).

```
?- irmao(mateus,isabela).
true .
```

Sugiro que faças esse tipo de composição de regras para encontrar tios, primos etcétera.

Antes de prosseguirmos, considere o seguinte exemplo:

```
digerindo(X,Y) :- comeu(X,Y).
digerindo(X,Y) :- comeu(X,Z), digerindo(Z,Y).

comeu(mosquito,sangue(joão)).
comeu(sapo,mosquito).
comeu(cegonha,sapo).
```

Bastante ordinárion, não? Uma base de conhecimento contendo dois fatos
e duas regras, mas a definição de digeringo/2 é recursiva e ocorre em ambos os lados da segunda regra. Crucialmente, contudo, há uma ponto de parada (um caso base) para o número de chamadas. Este ponto é dado pela regra comeu/1, que ocorre am ambos os lados
das duas regras

A primeira regra (que não é recursiva, ou como normalmente a chamamos, a cláusula base), simplesmente diz que: se X acabou de comer Y, então X não está digerindo Y.

Então, e a segunda regra, a regra recursiva? esta diz que: se X tiver comido Z e Z está digerindo Y,
então X está digerindo Y também. Logo, Prolog conclui por inferência que a consulta é verdadeira.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Finalmente, voltando ao seu problema, vamos encontra um ascendente(antepassado).

```
?- ascendente(jose,helio).
true .

?- ascendente(jose,fabiano).
true .
```

> Caso tu queiras um bom material em português, procure por **Eloi Favero**
>
> Fonte:  BLACKBURN, Patrick; BOS, Johannes; STRIEGNITZ, Kristina. Learn
> prolog now!. Londres: College Publications, 2006.